# How can I use the Refresh Token to generate a new Auth Token using the Google API (C#)?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, token, refresh

Please forgive me if this is a newbie question.  The below code works for the first hour, then the access token expires and it no longer works. I've read many places that the access token is supposed to be renewed using the refresh token but I don't see anywhere how that is done.  I use the generated access token to send email. Thanks for your help!

---

```
    private void GetClientSecrets()
    {
            // I don't like requesting this much access but I can't get it to work with less access
            string[] scopes = { "email", "profile", "https://mail.google.com/" };

            UserCredential credential;

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = _clientID,
                    ClientSecret = _clientSecret
                },
                scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(_credentialPath, true)).Result;

            var jwtPayload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(credential.Token.IdToken).Result;
            _username = jwtPayload.Email;
            _accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;

}

    public void SendGmail(string toEmail, string subject, string body, string replyTo = "", string cc = "", string bcc = "")
    {
            // Gmail SMTP server address
            SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");
            // enable SSL connection
            oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
            // Using 587 port, you can also use 465 port
            oServer.Port = 587;

            // use Gmail SMTP OAUTH 2.0 authentication
            oServer.AuthType = SmtpAuthType.XOAUTH2;
            // set user authentication
            oServer.User = _username;
            // use access token as password
            oServer.Password = _accessToken;
            oServer.MailFrom = _username;

            SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
            oMail.From = _username;
            oMail.To = toEmail;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cc))
            {
                oMail.Cc = cc;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replyTo))
            {
                oMail.ReplyTo = replyTo;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bcc))
            {
                oMail.Bcc = bcc;
            }

            oMail.Subject = subject;
            oMail.TextBody = body;

            if (SystemConfig.DebugMode)
            {
                Logger.SimpleWriteToLog($"Sending email from {_username} (reply to: {replyTo}) to {toEmail} (CC: {cc}, BCC: {bcc}) using OAUTH 2.0{Environment.NewLine}{subject}{Environment.NewLine}{body}");
            }

            EASendMail.SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();
            oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
    }
```

### }

**UPDATE** (2/12/2020)

I couldn't find how to do this in the API but this page shows you how you can do it using a POST.

Refreshing an access token

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#offline

Comment: Are you using google api console to create token? some of the google api need to pay if you exceed the limit. "https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server", Read the part "Exchange the authorization code for an access token", it has information to refresh token

Comment: According to the doc https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#credentials_1, you can set access_type=offline to make the access token auto refreshed.

Comment: Thanks charles and phonemyatt. Charles, After looking at the documentation it isn't' clear to me where I can set access_type=offline, do you know?

Comment: It feels that an access token is persisted in the `_accessToken` variable and never gets updated. The `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` method should be invoked each time before using an access token in the `oServer.Password = _accessToken;` statement. The `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` is smart enough to use an existing access token from the data storage if it has not been expired, or to refresh it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (2/12/2020)

I couldn't find how to do this in the API but this page shows you how you can do it using a POST.

Refreshing an access token

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#offline